# How to identify root cause from MINIDUMP? WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, debug, dump, minidumps

My computer keeps restarting on its own randomly, and sometimes when wake it up, the screen is all pixels so I suspect I have an issue related to my graphics card.

I'm new to `*.dmp` debugging, and I've collected a full dump and minidump and I'm trying to understand what it is telling me. [It's here if you'd like to download (5.39 mb)](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Apb-0nSp-ptA9V3KCpII9FT8gyCp).

In `WinDbg` I've run `!analyze -v` against the dump and the output is below:

```
PROCESSES_ANALYSIS: 1

SERVICE_ANALYSIS: 1

STACKHASH_ANALYSIS: 1

TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  To Be Filled By O.E.M.

SYSTEM_SKU:  To Be Filled By O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  To Be Filled By O.E.M.

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  P3.30

BIOS_DATE:  08/14/2018

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASRock

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  X399 Taichi

BASEBOARD_VERSION:                        

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 224c076f

BUGCHECK_P2: 11c4abe8000

BUGCHECK_P3: 11c4ac18e39

BUGCHECK_P4: 6

CPU_COUNT: 20

CPU_MHZ: da5

CPU_VENDOR:  AuthenticAMD

CPU_FAMILY: 17

CPU_MODEL: 8

CPU_STEPPING: 2

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x1CA

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  f

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  ASERV

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  05-23-2019 08:58:26.0066

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.18869.1002 amd64fre

BAD_STACK_POINTER:  fffff8076f4fdc68

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8076bae6335 to fffff8076b1bc8a0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff807`6f4fdc68 fffff807`6bae6335 : 00000000`000001ca 00000000`224c076f 0000011c`4abe8000 0000011c`4ac18e39 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff807`6f4fdc70 fffff807`6bad02da : 0000011c`4ac18e39 00000000`00000001 fffff807`6b350614 00000000`00000082 : hal!HalpWatchdogCheckPreResetNMI+0xd5
fffff807`6f4fdcb0 fffff807`6b2a1e8b : 00000000`00000001 0000011c`4ac186f7 fffff807`687be180 fffff807`6b2b2f10 : hal!HalpPreprocessNmi+0x1142a
fffff807`6f4fdce0 fffff807`6b1c7d42 : 00000000`00000001 fffff807`6f4fdef0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiProcessNMI+0xcb
fffff807`6f4fdd30 fffff807`6b1c7b11 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KxNmiInterrupt+0x82
fffff807`6f4fde70 fffff807`6b300bce : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiNmiInterrupt+0x211
fffff807`6f4e47a0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!PpmIdleGuestExecute+0x1e


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  87599f0eaef23e874d8ebbf91c6070b67940ba62

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  3cf1ed64da6380532909821111b1942804aae8e7

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  782650af79f96574cdba6be2f36ad0d2d7924552

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!KiProcessNMI+cb
fffff807`6b2a1e8b 488b3d06811a00  mov     rdi,qword ptr [nt!KiNmiCallbackListHead (fffff807`6b449f98)]

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  63d8b48

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!KiProcessNMI+cb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.18362.116

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  cb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x1CA_STACKPTR_ERROR_nt!KiProcessNMI

BUCKET_ID:  0x1CA_STACKPTR_ERROR_nt!KiProcessNMI

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x1CA_STACKPTR_ERROR_nt!KiProcessNMI

TARGET_TIME:  2019-05-23T03:14:04.000Z

OSBUILD:  18362

OSSERVICEPACK:  116

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  unknown_date

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  190318-1202

BUILDLAB_STR:  19h1_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  fd6

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x1ca_stackptr_error_nt!kiprocessnmi

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {09a889cd-f940-6da5-9668-0c0c98a7d643}
```

How can I make heads or tails of it? I see `ntkrnlmp.exe` but that's just the kernel process handling whatever is causing the problem it seems. My gut tells me it's the graphics driver, but I'm not seeing info to support that assumption.

Suggestions where to go?

Comment: It is a driver fault and graphics drivers are the biggest offenders for this type of bsod. Update the graphics driver and see if it solves it.

Comment: @Moab I have the latest graphics driver. What did you see that indicated the driver fault? The graphics card I have is NewEgg part `14-137-256` MSI Radeon RX 570...something that's been around a while so I'd think it'd be stable by now.

Answer (score 0):

I still am not 100% the root cause, but apparently the dump does not provide a ton of information beyond a `Watchdog` failure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer), which means there's some piece of hardware that is failing.

Well no kidding something is failing. I opened a ticket with Microsoft and that's the best they could tell me. They could **not** point to the specific component given the full dumps.

Answer (score -2):

Im the exact same with the same motherboard which doesnt have drivers for windows 10.
WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT is what youre getting, and your OS is Windows 10

Comment: What does this mean exactly? Please [edit] and clarify with more detail what you are answering. Don't respond to this comment which I will delete if you fix what I'm asking you to fix. Thanks!